# strategy.close don't close position when TP is hit

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm expecting this code to close the long position with market order

for SL, just on bar close if `low` is lower than stop loss (SL_long)

for TP, immediately on tick when `close` (the actual price, right?) is greater than take profit (TP_long)

```
if (inLong)
    if (low <= SL_long)
        strategy.close("Long Order", comment="Long SL Hit", qty=fullPosSize, alert_message = customAlert)
    if (close >= TP_long)
        strategy.close("Long Order", comment="Long TP Hit", qty=fullPosSize, alert_message = customAlert, immediately = true)
```

It does not seem to work, please check image attached

[trade not exited properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNzcC.png)

I tried adding immediately parameter but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

When your script is run on historical candles, it will only ever run once per candle close. Therefore, your take profit comparison code will compare the candle's closing price against the take profit price; hence, it doesn't detect the TP being hit.

The code you posted will only work as expected on realtime candles and only when you have `calc_on_every_tick` enabled in your `strategy()` call.

Instead of manually closing positions when the TP / SL is hit, why don't you use `strategy.exit()` with the `limit` and `stop` parameters set to your TP / SL price?

```js
if longConditionIsTrue and strategy.position_size == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry("Long Order", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long Order", limit = TP_long, stop = SL_long, alert_profit = customAlert, alert_loss = customAlert)
```

This way, TradingView's broker emulator will automatically exit you from an active position when the TP or SL is hit.

Comment: thank you Whitebox, it's now clearer.

I was using strategy.exit, but changed it to strategy.close to get (safer) market orders on the exchange (thru the alert via webhook).
As the alert is sent by the closing function, if I switch back to strategy.exit, will the order be executed as market order, on time as I'm expecting (rules above)

Comment: How your exit order is executed in TradingView's broker emulator shouldn't influence the type of order you use on the exchange to exit your trade. All you need from your script is to send an alert when the price hits your TP or SL. If you want an alert to be sent the moment the TP or SL is hit, you can use the `alert_profit` and `alert_loss` arguments to `strategy.exit()`. I've updated the answer to use the alert arguments.

Comment: I thought TV emulator would pass thru all historic bars prices, not just ohlc, at least simulating movement (no real intrabar ticks)..

In your code Stop Loss would trigger immediately right? I'd like to "ignore wicks" and just exit the position if bar close is above/under SL levels

Also `strategy.position_size == 0` would not allow strategy.exit to be executed on each bar.. or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: So I'm also trying this code with no success
`if (close >= TP_long)`
        `strategy.exit("Long Order", comment="Long TP Hit", qty=fullPosSize, alert_message = customAlert, limit = TP_long)`

position is exit on TP just on the next bar, not at the right price level

Comment: Uhm.. I think I should separate exit orders.. right? for SL use strategy.close and for TP use strategy.exit

Comment: If you want to wait for a candle to close before you consider it touching your TP/SL, you cannot use `strategy.exit()`. In that case, you need to use `strategy.close()`.